# Eclipse plugin for lazy Android developers

Tags: software-development, eclipse

I'm looking for an Eclipse plugin or tool that would make Android application development easier and faster.

Here are some feature I'd like to have:

- Automatically make the connection between the XML and Java activities, link all the widgets
- Make a class automatically parcelable
- Create a adapted list in a few clicks
- Create a SQLite helper Java class easily in a few clicks

Comment: Being lazy motivates you. Create these if they don't already exist so you can help other lazy developers :D

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Automatically make the connection between the XML and Java activities, link all the widgets

There's a couple different ways to accomplish this. One of them is through using a dependency inject framework like [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/index.html). Via the Butter Knife website are the instructuctions for setting up Butter Knife for Eclipse.[2](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-eclipse.html)

Here's a basic example borrowed from their website:

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @InjectView(R.id.title) TextView title;
  @InjectView(R.id.subtitle) TextView subtitle;
  @InjectView(R.id.footer) TextView footer;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    // TODO Use "injected" views...
  }
}
```

And you can use Butter Knife for among other things to inject `OnClickListeners` like so:

```
@OnClick(R.id.submit)
public void submit(View view) {
  // TODO submit data to server...
}
```

And there's even an Android Studio plugin [ButterKnifeZelezny](https://github.com/inmite/android-butterknife-zelezny) that autogenerates these view injections.

However if you are not interested in ButterKnife then there is a [Lazy Android 1.0.0.61](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/lazy-android)

> Make a class automatically parcelable

There is an Eclipse plugin called [Parcelable generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/parcelablegenerator/) however I haven't used it, but I have used a similar plugin for Android Studio called [android-parcelable-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin) that will "...generate those tedious findViewById declarations."

> Create a adapted list in a few clicks

I haven't used either of these libraries but there appears to be [android-codegenerator-plugin-intellij](https://github.com/tmorcinek/android-codegenerator-plugin-intellij) which supports generating Adapter Class code from item layout. Also there is [AndroidStudioTemplate](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/AndroidStudioTemplate) which according to its documentation supports "Array Adapter: Creates a new Custom Array Adapter with a ViewHolder pattern."

> Create a SQLite helper Java class easily in a few clicks

I don't have any experience with it but [ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid) is an ORM that "...allows you to save and retrieve SQLite database records without ever writing a single SQL statement."

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much